# R package 'smacof' Error in w %*% external : non-conformable arguments

Tags: r

I'm having an issue and I have no idea what's going on. Basically, I need to run multidimensional scaling with covariates using `smacof` and `vegan` R packages, but I obtain the following error `Error in w %*% external : non-conformable arguments`.

Below are my steps

1) Use `vegan` to obtain the dissimilarity matrix.

```
output<-metaMDS(data[,1:80], stress=.05, k=6, trymax=1000, trace = TRUE)
```

2) Convert dissimilarity into matrix form. Define covariates.

```
delta <- matrix(0, ncol = 80, nrow = 80)
delta[lower.tri(delta)] <- output$diss
covariate<-data[,81:82]
```

3) Use `smacof`

```
result<-smacofConstraint(delta, constraint="linear", external=covariate,
                       ndim=6, type="ordinal", itmax=1000, verbose=TRUE)
```

However, I obtain the following error:

```
`Error in w %*% external : non-conformable arguments`
```

Any help would be great!!!

Comment: Please provide `dim(delta)` and `dim(covariate)`.

Comment: `dim(delta)`=80*80 and `dim(covariate)`=97*2

Comment: You have discrepancy between the sizes of `delta` and `covariate`.